# Cant access an image file

Tags: image, file, xamarin, imageview, filesystems

I'm creating and app using Xamarin.ios in VS mac. I'm trying to add an image to my app, but for some reason I can't get the image from a file.

```
        public UIImage getImage(string name)
        {
            UIImage image;
            image = UIImage.FromFile("Images/blt.png");

            if(image is null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Image IS Null;
                
            }


            }
            return image;
        }
```

I keep getting Image IS Null.
I've tried using relative and absolute path. And placing the image in different folders.
Any help would be great.

Comment: resources are NOT files.  Have you read the docs on using images in iOS?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos

Comment: @Jason Yeah, I've tried putting them into an Images folder as well.

Comment: Again, I suggest you read the docs

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. It helped. For reference, I partially followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/customizing-table-appearance which led me astray.